# Local host: 8000, refuses to connect when attempting to run using Visual Studio Code

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, localhost

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlSOc.jpg)I'm trying to execute a program using Vue.JS and I'm using a rich-text editor visual studio code, but every time I hit the run command I get this error:

Local host: 8000, refused to connect. Please see the image attached.

Comment: Something might already be running on port 8000 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `lsof -i :8000` to check if that port is already busy.

If something is running try running `kill -9 <PID>` for killing it.

Answer (score 0):

I get it, I did not run the npm run serve command on terminal in VS Code that's why it gave me an error as what I've posted. It's 100% working now.[I've inserted the image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRIUq.jpg)

I appreciate your answer Mr. Dipansh Khandewal. Thank you :)